# CruiseControl Console error message when parsing XML

Tags: c#, xml, cruisecontrol.net

I have CruiseControl(1.5) running in Win2k8R2 and svn(1.6.9) The error happens on a successful build after nant(0.86) Timeout(600 seconds). When I check the build dir everything is built correctly but CruiseControl Dashboard report Exception

Here is the error shown in console:

```
[:DEBUG] Exception: System.Xml.XmlException: The ',' character, hexadecimal value 0x2C, cannot be included in a name. Line 5544, position 274.
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
  at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
  at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util.XmlFragmentWriter.WriteNode(XmlReader reader, Boolean defattr)
  at ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Util.XmlFragmentWriter.WriteNode(String xml)
```

Comment: Go to Line 5544, position 274 and remove the `,` character

Answer (score 1):

Generaly, this error happens when ccnet is trying to merge **Nant ouput with non-xml info** into the build report.

Verify the Nant ouput.

Maybe something similar here:
[CruiseControl.Net complaining about xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/594429/cruisecontrol-net-complaining-about-xml)